# Can `git reset -q` be equivalent to some `git reset` command without `-q`?

Tags: git

The manpage  of `git reset` says

> ```
> git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…
> ```
>
> This form resets the index entries for all  `<paths>`  to their state at
>   `<tree-ish>` . (It does not affect the working tree or the current
>   branch.) This means that  git reset `<paths>`  is the opposite of  `git
>   add <paths>` .

I am thinking that the above form of command requires `-q`. But does `[-q]` mean that `-q` is optional? If yes, what is its difference with the following command?

> ```
> git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]
> ```
>
> This form resets the current branch head to  `<commit>`  and possibly
>   updates the index (resetting it to the tree of  `<commit>` ) and the
>   working tree depending on  `<mode>` . If  `<mode>`  is omitted,
>   defaults to  `--mixed` .

Isn't the first form `git reset -q HEAD [--] <paths>…` the same as

```
git reset mixed HEAD [--] <paths>…
```

?

Note that I believe the `git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]` can be added with `[--] <paths>...` at the end, because it is shown in the output of the following command:

```
$ git rm feature2file 
rm 'feature2file'
$ git status
On branch feature2
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature2' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    feature2file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-q` flag *is* optional and is implied by a non-empty `<paths>...` part.  For instance:

```
git reset HEAD feature2file
```

has one `<path>` argument, namely `feature2file`, so this implies the `-q` flag.

> ... what is its difference with ... `git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]`

That command, which lacks any `<path>` arguments, invokes a different mode of operation of `git reset`.

There are some people (including myself) who think these should have always been two different front-end Git commands, to reduce the possibility of confusion.  But they're not, so we are stuck with this confusion.

> Isn't the first form `git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…` the same as `git reset --mixed HEAD [--] <paths>…`?

(I fixed your un-dashed `mixed` to read `--mixed`).  It would be *if* the latter were allowed.  It is, at least officially, not allowed, but:

```
$ git reset --mixed HEAD -- Makefile
warning: --mixed with paths is deprecated; use 'git reset -- <paths>' instead.
```

Note that `--hard` and `--soft` are ruled out:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD -- Makefile
fatal: Cannot do soft reset with paths.
$ git reset --hard HEAD -- Makefile
fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.
```

The case of `--mixed`, which is the default if `[<mode>]` is omitted, and `[<commit>]` being optional and defaulting to `HEAD`, means that:

```
git reset hello
```

is ambiguous:

- Does it fit the `git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]` pattern, where `mode` is omitted (defaulted to `--mixed`) and `hello` is translated to a commit via the six-step rules in the gitrevisions documentation?  Yes, clearly it fits that pattern.
- Does it fit the `git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <files>...` pattern, where `<tree-ish>` is omitted and `<files>` is the file name `hello`?  Yes, it clearly fits *that* pattern too.

Which one does `git reset` use?  The answer is: it's coded to try out both, and if both *could* apply, produce an error message:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'wt-status.c': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

This problem would not arise if there were separate commands for the different modes of operation.

Comment: Thanks. Can `git reset` be used to update the working directory and index of the repository, without changing which commit is the head commit of the current branch? (1) Can the first form work for the purpose? By `<paths>...`, does it apply only to individual files, or can it also apply to the entire working directory of the repository?
(2) The second form doesn't seem to work for the purpose, because it changes which commit is the head commit of the current branch.

Comment: Yes, you can reset the index and work-tree without *changing* the current commit by choosing the current commit as the new commit (so that Git rewrites `HEAD` to itself). The `-q` form of `git reset`, which is really a different command, does not touch the work-tree and does not change `HEAD` in any way.

Comment: How "you can reset the index and work-tree without changing the current commit by choosing the current commit as the new commit (so that Git rewrites HEAD to itself)"? Is it by `reset` or not?

Comment: `git reset [<mode>] HEAD` reads the current value of `HEAD`, then writes that value back to `HEAD`. Exercise: What happens if some variable `x` is set to 12 and then you set variable `x` to 12? (1) Was the variable *set?* (2) If so, did the variable *change?*